# Pandas DataFrame column split and sum

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` as the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['Bay of Plenty', 'Bell Rd, Nukuhou','Nukuhou, Bay of Plenty'],[1.0, 0.5,1.0]]).T
df.columns = ['col1','col2']

    col1    col2
0   Bay of Plenty   1
1   Bell Rd, Nukuhou    0.5
2   Nukuhou, Bay of Plenty  1
```

I want to get the following output.

```
col1    sum
Bay of Plenty   2.0     
Nukuhou     1.5     
Bell Rd     0.5
```

I tried the following.

```
df["splited"]=df["col1"].str.split(",")
df = (df.explode("splited").reset_index(drop=True))

    col1    col2    splited
0   Bay of Plenty   1   Bay of Plenty
1   Bell Rd, Nukuhou    0.5     Bell Rd
2   Bell Rd, Nukuhou    0.5     Nukuhou
3   Nukuhou, Bay of Plenty  1   Nukuhou
4   Nukuhou, Bay of Plenty  1   Bay of Plenty

df.groupby(['splited']).sum().reset_index()
```

But this is not giving the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` by `,` with space - `,` :

```
#whitespaces
print(df["col1"].str.split(",").tolist())
[['Bay of Plenty'], ['Bell Rd', ' Nukuhou'], ['Nukuhou', ' Bay of Plenty']] 
                                ^^^                      ^^^
#no whitespaces
print(df["col1"].str.split(", ").tolist())
[['Bay of Plenty'], ['Bell Rd', 'Nukuhou'], ['Nukuhou', 'Bay of Plenty']]
```

---

```
df["splited"]=df["col1"].str.split(", ")
df = df.explode("splited")

df = df.groupby('splited')['col2'].sum().reset_index() 
print(df)
         splited  col2
0  Bay of Plenty   2.0
1        Bell Rd   0.5
2        Nukuhou   1.5
```

Another idea is use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove trailing whitespaces:

```
df["splited"]=df["col1"].str.split(",")
df = df.explode("splited")

df = df.groupby(df['splited'].str.strip())['col2'].sum().reset_index() 
print(df)
         splited  col2
0  Bay of Plenty   2.0
1        Bell Rd   0.5
2        Nukuhou   1.5
```

EDIT:

If need split by one or no space after `,` is possible regex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Bay of Plenty', 'Bell Rd, Nukuhou',
                    'Nukuhou,Bay of Plenty'],[1.0, 0.5,1.0]]).T
df.columns = ['col1','col2']

df["splited"]=df["col1"].str.split(",\s*")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works well. I can see str.split(",") adds a whitespace? Could you please explain why that happens?

Comment: @Philips - no, if use `,` with no space then there is traling spaces, so different between `' Bay of Plenty'` and `'Bay of Plenty'` - so in groupby are processing like different strings.

Comment: @Philips - and if use `, ` (with space) all working correct, because separator remove comma and space after it.